# How does List<SelectListItem> safely cast to SelectList in view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I was following a question where the OP had something like this

```
[HttpGet]
public  ActionResult Index() {
   var options = new List<SelectListItem>();

   options.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Text1", Value = "1" });
   options.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Text2", Value = "2" });
   options.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Text3", Value = "3" });

   ViewBag.Status = options;

   return View();
}
```

And then in the view was able to do something like this

```
@Html.DropDownList("Status", ViewBag.Status as SelectList)
```

My expectation was that the result of the cast would be `null` and I stated as much. I was corrected that it should work and it was demonstrated via .net fiddle. To my surprise the dropdownlist was populated with the items.

My question: How is it that when done in the view, `List<SelectListItem>` safely casts to `SelectList`

Comment: I think the cast returns null. It works because the first parameter of `@Html.DropDownList` has the same name as the ViewData/ViewBag property (i.e. "Status"). Just remove the cast from the fiddle in question. It will work. https://dotnetfiddle.net/KRxJhN

Comment: Good catch! I think it is the answer

Comment: @AndreiOlariu This should be an answer

Comment: To confirm @AndreiOlariu using a console app: https://dotnetfiddle.net/codVBw  I couldn't even use `as` to cast until I made the list enumerable.

Comment: But this works in the fiddle: `@Html.DropDownList("Status")`

Comment: @AndreiOlariu, you are correct. I just tested that as well and it worked. Good catch.

Comment: The "as" cast works on `object` (what ViewData["Status"] returns) and `dynamic` (ViewBag.Status). I assume because the compiler cannot know for sure the cast is not valid.

Comment: @AndreiOlariu - I was confirming what you were saying, sorry if it was confusing.  I just pulled it out into a console app to try to simplify your second statement, that the second parameter was irrelevant.

Comment: That's fine, I got that. I was trying to explain it to myself as well. Thanks @ps2goat!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This was a good question. I looked into the matter further and, indeed, if the `selectList` parameter is null, then the `name` parameter is used to look up a key in `ViewData`.

I'm basing this on http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/5cb74eb3b2f3#src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/SelectExtensions.cs

They even added a comment:

```
private static MvcHtmlString SelectInternal(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, ModelMetadata metadata, string optionLabel, string name, IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList, bool allowMultiple, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)
{
    ...
    // If we got a null selectList, try to use ViewData to get the list of items.
    if (selectList == null)
    {
       selectList = htmlHelper.GetSelectData(name);
       ...
```

And later on, the `name` is used:

```
private static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetSelectData(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string name)
{
    object o = null;
    if (htmlHelper.ViewData != null)
    {
        o = htmlHelper.ViewData.Eval(name);
    }
    ...
```

Good question @Nkosi. I had no idea this was possible.